# How to publish to MacOS using windows Visual Studio

Tags: macos, visual-studio, publish

I have written a program using Visual studio that I want to publish to multiple platforms. I have winodws OS.
if you publish to windows it gives me a .exe file that I can run
but if I publish to MacOS it gives me a file with no extension and I don't know how my friends should run it on their mac.
[image]
generated output file is:
[image]

I don't have MacOS myself but does anyone know what I should tell my friends with MacOS to do in order to execute that file?

Comment: Just run it? Unix-based operating systems don't use the extension to identify the file type. It may be required to edit the properties and allow execution, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you can constrain yourself to .NET Core or newer, you can publish according to this Microsoft document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs

The documentation talks about Linux but that includes macOS in this case too.